# Is it safe to use unsynchronized mutable state with Kotlin Flow?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Is following code safe and why?

```kotlin
val flow: Flow<String> = ...
val allStrings = mutableListOf<String>()
var sum = 0

flow.transform {
  allStrings += it
  emit(it.toInt())
}.collect {
  sum += it
}
```

Following test demonstrates `collect {}` body being called from different threads:

```kotlin
val ctx = newFixedThreadPoolContext(32, "my-context")

runBlocking(ctx) {
    val f = flow<Int> {
        (1 .. 1000).forEach {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
    
    var t: Thread? = null
    f.collect {
        delay(1)
        // this requirement will fail
        if (t == null) t = Thread.currentThread() else require(t == Thread.currentThread())
    }
}
```

And another one that tests publication:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ctx = newFixedThreadPoolContext(32, "my-context")
    runBlocking(ctx) {
        val f = flow<Int> {
            (1 .. 1000000).forEach {
                emit(it)
            }
        }
        var c = 0
        f.transform {
            c += 1
            boo()
            c += 1
            emit(it)
            c += 1
        }.collect {
            c += 1
            boo()
            c += 1
        }
        println(c) // prints 5_000_000
    }
}
suspend fun boo() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    }
}
```

Therefore it *seems* kotlin flow ensures publication between coroutine invocations but is this intentional (or even documented) or implementation side effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code is safe. [Flows are sequential](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows-are-sequential) by default.

> Each individual collection of a flow is performed sequentially unless
> special operators that operate on multiple flows are used. The
> collection works directly in the coroutine that calls a terminal
> operator (`collect`). No new coroutines are launched by default. Each
> emitted value is processed by all the intermediate operators from
> upstream to downstream and is then delivered to the terminal operator
> after.

Kotlin Flows are based on suspending functions and they are completely sequential, but not single-threaded.

> Therefore it seems kotlin flow ensures publication between coroutine invocations but is this intentional (or even documented) or implementation side effect?

[Here it says](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow):

> a flow is a type that can emit multiple values sequentially

According to this I understand that no new value will be collected until previous value is processed, no matter how much Threads are involved.

As Roman mention in his comment, here is a [good article](https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292) about **sequential execution**. A great quote from there:

> Even though a coroutine in Kotlin can execute on multiple threads it is just like a thread from a standpoint of mutable state. No two actions in the same coroutine can be concurrent. And just like with threads you should avoid sharing your mutable state between coroutines or you’ll have to worry about synchronization yourself.
> Avoid sharing mutable state. Confine each mutable object to either a single thread or to a single coroutine and sleep well.

And this is applicable to `Flows`, because collection of `Flow` works directly in the coroutine that calls a terminal operator. No new coroutines are launched by default.

Comment: It does not say all flow operations are run in the same thread, only in the same context which can be run on multi-thread threadpool

Comment: Right, but Kotlin Flows are based on suspending functions and they are completely sequential.

Comment: I think no it is not. Just put thread check into our code into `transform {}` block and it triggered. Therefore while flows are sequential it is programmer's responsibility to care about publication. Unless flow implementation ensures publication before every invocation of `transform` lambda.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "I think no it is not". I see in your updated question the example you posted (5_000_000) seems correct: there are 3 increments in `transform`, two in `collect` and overall emits are 1_000_000, so no increments are lost.

Comment: I meant sequential - yes, single-threaded - no, thread safe - likely yes but no guarantees so far.

Comment: Right, the are not single threaded.

Comment: To understand the technical meaning of the word "sequential" I can suggest some additional reading here https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292